# Sub Grid Total In Crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a primary Entity (Self-Insurance) and a secondary entity (Compensation). They have a 1:N relationship. So in my main form of Self Insurance I have a sub-grid with the name  'Worker_Compensation' where i am adding up some payroll values. 
I have 2 questions. . .

1: The thing I want is that when I add some values in the sub-grid. I need to show a sum of all payrolls in the text below of my main form named as 'TOTAL'.

2: Where should i call this java script(On which event) Onload or Onsave of form ? or else where because I can seems to locate the events on Subgrid.

I am using a java script for this purpose.

```
enter code here
function setupGridRefresh() {
var targetgrid = document.getElementById("Worker_Compensation");

// If already loaded
if (targetgrid.readyState == 'complete') {
    targetgrid.attachEvent("onrefresh", subGridOnload);
}
else {
    targetgrid.onreadystatechange = function applyRefreshEvent() {
        var targetgrid = document.getElementById("Worker_Compensation");
        if (targetgrid.readyState == 'complete') {
            targetgrid.attachEvent("onrefresh", subGridOnload);
        }
    }
}
subGridOnload();
}

function subGridOnload() {
//debugger;
var grid = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('Worker_Compensation')._control;
var sum = 0.00;

if (grid.get_innerControl() == null) {
    setTimeout(subGridOnload, 1000);
    return;
}
else if (grid.get_innerControl()._element.innerText.search("Loading") != -1) {
    setTimeout(subGridOnload, 1000);
    return;
}

var ids = grid.get_innerControl().get_allRecordIds();
var cellValue;
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (grid.get_innerControl().getCellValue('new_estannualpayroll', ids[i]) != "") {
        cellValue = grid.get_innerControl().getCellValue('new_estannualpayroll', ids[i]);
        cellValue = cellValue.substring(2);
        cellValue = parseFloat(cellValue);
        sum = sum + cellValue;
    }

}

var currentSum = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_payrolltotal').getValue();
if (sum > 0 || (currentSum != sum && currentSum != null)) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_payrolltotal').setValue(sum);
}
}
```

This piece of code is not working. after i add values in the grid my textbox remains empty!
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a supported way to achieve what you want. if this is a MUST and you can't change the way i would recomend a plug-in that sums the values you need on the parent entity and if you need to see that value without waiting a refresh on the form, make a async js that checks if that value has changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with subgrid's onRefresh. This is also unsupportted way but it works. You must add this functions to your javascript

```js
function AddEventToGridRefresh(gridName, functionToCall) {
   // retrieve the subgrid
   var grid = document.getElementById(gridName);
   // if the subgrid still not available we try again after 1 second
   if (grid == null) {
       setTimeout(function () {AddEventToGridRefresh(gridName, functionToCall);}, 1000);
       return;
   }
   // add the function to the onRefresh event
   grid.control.add_onRefresh(functionToCall);
}
// function used in this example
function AdviseUser() {
   alert("Sub-Grid refreshed");
}
```

For more information, here is the [link](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/07/bind-function-to-subgrid-refresh.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading to Microsoft CRM 2015 soon or are already on Microsoft CRM 2015, you can do this without any JavaScript by simply creating a new calculated rollup field and placing that underneath the sub grid, or wherever you wish to place it on the form.  Note that this field is calculated ever 12 hours, but if you wish to, it could be calculated on form load via JavaScript.  You can see details about that at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817863.aspx -"Calculated and Rollup Attributes".  The TechNet document, "Define rollup fields" at https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn832162.aspx has some good examples, scenarios, and discussion about the limitations of the rollup fields.